# Inserting Test Data into SQL Table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to get some test data inserted into a MySQL database, which has a mixture of reference ID's and variable values.  My statement, rejected by MySQL with it's generic (and patently next to worthless) "syntax error near xxx" error is:

```
INSERT INTO TimeSlotWorker (TimeSlotId, WorkerId, PostCode, CitySuburbName)
SELECT                      TimeSlotId, 1       , PostCode, CitySuburbName
FROM (
              SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 1), '2914' AS PostCode, '' AS CitySuburbName
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2), '2912'            , ''
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2), '2913'            , ''
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2), '2911'            , ''
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Charnwood'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Dunlop'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Florey'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Flynn'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Fraser'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Higgins'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Holt'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Kippax'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Latham'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Macgregor'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Melba'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2615'            , 'Spence'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2614'            , 'Aranda'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3), '2614'            , 'Cook'
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 4), '2617'            , ''
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 5), '2602'            , ''
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 5), '2612'            , ''
    UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 6), '2609'            , ''
    )
```

which gives:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''2914' AS PostCode, '' AS CitySuburbName UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId FROM Time' at line 4

Expecting this to insert 22 records where for each one the singular TimeSlotId comes from an existing record and I was trying to avoid hard coding its generated ID.

1. Where have I gone wrong, first of all?
2. Is there a better way?
3. Can this be extrapolated to insert multiple records for each sub-SELECT with DayCode varying through MON, TUE ... SAT?

Comment: The syntax error is pretty exact; it's the comma in front of `'2914'` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every one of the UNION-ed together SELECT statements has the same syntax error and cannot be parsed.  Consider the first one in isolation

```
SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot 
   WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 1), 
  '2914' AS PostCode, '' AS CitySuburbName
```

Those extra column names must all be before the FROM keyword:

```
SELECT TimeSlotId, '2914' AS PostCode, '' AS CitySuburbName
   FROM TimeSlot 
   WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 1),
```

Separately, the whole SELECT FROM (SELECT) construction is unnecessary  Instead you can INSERT the UNIONed together SELECT statements directly:

```
 INSERT INTO Table (ColList)
    SELECT SameNumberOfColumns FROM OtherTable WHERE . . .
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SameNumberOfColumns FROM OtherTable WHERE . . .
```

(and so on)

Answer (score 2):

To make your current code to work change it to

```sql
INSERT INTO TimeSlotWorker (TimeSlotId, WorkerId, PostCode, CitySuburbName)
SELECT                      TimeSlotId, 1       , PostCode, CitySuburbName
FROM 
(
            SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 1) TimeSlotId, '2914' PostCode, '' CitySuburbName
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2)           , '2912'         , ''
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2)           , '2913'         , ''
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2)           , '2911'         , ''
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Charnwood'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Dunlop'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Florey'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Flynn'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Fraser'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Higgins'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Holt'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Kippax'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Latham'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Macgregor'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Melba'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2615'         , 'Spence'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2614'         , 'Aranda'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3)           , '2614'         , 'Cook'
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 4)           , '2617'         , ''
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 5)           , '2602'         , ''
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 5)           , '2612'         , ''
  UNION ALL SELECT (SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 6)           , '2609'         , ''
) q
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01ea6/1)** demo

You can rewrite it this way

```sql
INSERT INTO TimeSlotWorker (TimeSlotId, WorkerId, PostCode, CitySuburbName)
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2914', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 1 UNION ALL 
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2912', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2913', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2911', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Charnwood' FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Dunlop'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Florey'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Flynn'     FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Fraser'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Higgins'   FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Holt'      FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Kippax'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Latham'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Macgregor' FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Melba'     FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2615', 'Spence'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2614', 'Aranda'    FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2614', 'Cook'      FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 3 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2617', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 4 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2602', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 5 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2612', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 5 UNION ALL
SELECT TimeSlotId, 1, '2609', ''          FROM TimeSlot WHERE DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 6
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e281/1)** demo

Comment: Thanks, got there from @GolezTrol's answer. Does the `UNION ALL` "belong" to the SELECT which follows it, or the one which precedes it? Just curious because for the former I prefer my layout, but for the latter, yours.

Comment: Since you're using `SELECT TimeSlotId FROM TimeSlot ...` to get a scalar value along with other values, which you specified after this select, you need to wrap it in an outer select and `UNION ALL` clauses belong to that outer SELECTs. In the latter example all constant values are brought into `SELECT ... FROM TimeSlot ...` therefore you don't need an outer select and `UNION ALL` belong right to these SELECTs.

Comment: UNION ALL doesn't belong to either, or it belongs to both. It links the two queries together, so UNION ALL cannot exist if there are no two queries.

Comment: @GolezTrol Thanks for clarification, but if you take a closer look OP specifically put `belong` in double quotes for lack of a better word and I used it my comment in the same context.

Answer (score 1):

.1. You subquery had only one column, TimeslotId, while in the main query, you select three (PostCode and CitySuburbName as well). That's not really a syntax error, but it is incorrect. The syntax error is in the fact that you *do* add those missing fields after the select statement, while they should be part of it.

You'll need to format the subquery like this:

```
          SELECT TimeSlotId, '2914' AS PostCode, '' AS CitySuburbName FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 1)
UNION ALL SELECT TimeSlotId, '2912', '' FROM TimeSlot WHERE (DayCode = 'MON' AND SequenceNbr = 2)
UNION ALL ...
```

So, make the constant value for PostCode and CitySuburbName part of the field list. You cannot just paste them after the select statement.

.2. I think this is a pretty good way. One of the best. :)

.3. I'm not sure what you mean, but it sounds like you can just leave `DayCode` out of the where clause, so each query in the union returns multiple records.

Comment: So I have to repeat the `AS PostCode` and `AS CitySuburbName` in each `UNION ALL` line of the subquery?  Or can I omit them still?

Comment: You need to move the values so they are part of the subselects. In your case you just pasted them after the `where` clause, which is the wrong place. You only need the aliases themselves in the first subquery of the union, like you already did. In the others you just need the value, and not the alias (you can add it, but it is ignored).